# View controller or something else for all iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i'm new to Xcode so this may be an easy question.
i'm building app for iOS devices (Universal), orientated only for landscape. My view controller size is for iPhone 4-inch. Is there a way to have an universal view controller or something else, that my app would be compatible with iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6 ...

Comment: yes, look into AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should research auto layout constraints to understand how view controllers and their subviews can be sized to dynamically react to different iPhone form factors and orientation changes (portrait vs. landscape).

Check out the following tutorial for a good run down:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

I have also found the WWDC videos on AutoLayout very educational.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which iOS target you are setting as your minimum. If you are targeting iOS 6 and above then @dgangsta's answer will allow your screen objects to react to a different screen size and layout your screen based on set constraints.

If you are targeting iOS 8 and above then I suggest looking at size class as well as auto layout. This will allow you to have a specific screen layout for each screen size and all managed in one view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop on iOS6 later.

You could use AutoLayout.

That can use on xib and storyboard and reduce many code.

Clearly Introduce

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

iOS Developer Library
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html